# Calculating angle of rectangle based on four lengths

Tags: geometry

I have two parallel walls and a rectangle in between. On the small sides of the rectangle I have respectively two sensors that are measuring the distance to the walls. These sensors are aligned symmetrically. The rectangle is able to move in x and y direction.

How can the angle between the rectangle and the wall be calculated using the four measured lengthes?
[image]

Comment: It can't. You'll need to have a distance between the sensors to do that.

Comment: @CiaPan The sensors have a fixed offset from the "centerline" of the rectangle. This offset is equal for all four sensors, therefore they are aligned symmetrically

Comment: For the angle calculation it doesn't matter if they are placed symmetrically, what is important is how far apart they are.

Comment: $L_1 + L_2  = L_3 + L_4$ implies anyone sensor is just the linear combination of the other 3. One sensor can be saved if the detection of the required angle is the only mission,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $w$ – the distance between sensors 2 and 3, then:
$$\tan\alpha = \frac{L_2 - L_3}w$$
and
$$\alpha = \arctan\frac{L_2 - L_3}w$$

[image]